# How to prevent Continuity / Handoff app icons in Dock?

Tags: ios, mac, dock, web-browser, continuity

Sometimes I open my iPhone while working at my Mac.

This often triggers a [Continuity / Handoff app icon](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681) to suddenly  appear in my Dock:

[image: Safari > From iPhone]

> **Safari**
>   From iPhone

I find it extremely irritating to constantly have this new Dock icon flashing in the periphery of my vision, and to see the Dock itself resizing to fit the new icon.

The worst offender is the current macOS default web browser. Many iOS apps offer to open their current URL on the Mac, which flashes Safari or Chrome in your macOS dock.

---

#### How can I prevent Handoff icons from appearing in the macOS Dock?

Is there a way to selectively prevent handing off **URLs or browser tabs**?

I may want to keep some Handoff Dock icons, but definitely not the generic Browser opening action.

---

<sup>**NOTE:** I do not want to fully disable Continuity, as I do rely on other features such as a shared Clipboard.</sup>

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to control parts of Continuity. It's either On or Off.

Comment: Less irritating would be a smaller size of icons (optionally with size animation while hovering) and auto hide dock.